UTM : How to boot with a custom ISO?
I have a MacBook Air with a M1 chip, and I want to create a VM with UTM using a specific boot ISO image, and I don't know if it possible or not. Here's he way I take for create a VM with my boot ISO image : + -> Virtualize -> Operating System: Other -> Browse: path/to/my/file.iso -> continue -> continue -> continue -> continue -> save
Here's the Summary before save : 
Here's, the infos of the VM : 
And here's the VM when he was booted : 
I don't know how I can properly launch my custom ISO, all I understand is when this shell show up, it mean the ISO file is not correctly read.
My problem : I don't know how to launch my custom boot ISO image with UTM like VirtualBox Studio, so I ask you for help if someone have the solution.
I have the latest stable version of of UTM, same for Sonoma.
Thank everyone in advance for answers !

Please don't post text as an image; see Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?.

Is the software ARM or x86?  You've created an ARM virtual machine.
